# Calcular diferença de data e printar esses dias

Tags: php, data, dateinterval

Eu gostaria de calcular a diferença de duas datas e imprimir todas as datas entre elas, por exemplo:

```
$data_inicio = new DateTime("08-02-2018");
$data_fim = new DateTime("10-03-2018");
($dateInterval = $data_inicio->diff($data_fim);
echo $dateInterval->days;
```

meu retorno é : **30**.

O que eu gostaria de ter era os dias que estão nesse intervalo.

Exemplo: **09-02-2018**, **10-02-2018** ..... **09-03-2018** e etc.

Como eu faço para recuperar esses valores?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode interar sobre as duas datas com um simples `for`, a classe [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php), existe um metodo `add` que pode ser inserido um [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.dateinterval.php) para uma nova data com um valor no seu construtor `P1D`, ou seja, um dia a mais na data, exemplo:

```
<?php

$data_inicio = new DateTime("2018-02-08");
$data_fim = new DateTime("2018-03-10");
$dateInterval = $data_inicio->diff($data_fim);
echo $dateInterval->days;
$datas = array();
for($i = $data_inicio; $i < $data_fim; $i = $data_inicio->add(new DateInterval('P1D')) )
{
    $datas[] = $i->format("d/m/Y");

}

print_r($datas);
```

[Exemplo Online Ideone](https://ideone.com/K2WcsS)

***Referencias:***

- [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php)
- [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.dateinterval.php)

Answer (score 3):

Você pode dar uma olhada nessa classe [DatePeriod](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) no php.net:

```
$periodo = new DatePeriod(
     new DateTime('2018-02-08'),
     new DateInterval('P1D'),
     new DateTime('2018-03-10')
);
```

Ela irá te retornar um array de DateTimes.

Para iterar neles:

```
foreach ($periodo as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($value->format('d-m-Y'));
}
```

Exemplo no [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/MHazjN)

Fonte: www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php

Comment: David, se você tirou esta reposta do SO em outro idioma coloque o link como referência por favor.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar um laço de repetição. Basta capturar o retorno em dias e utilizar um `for`, por exemplo:

```
$data_inicio = new DateTime("08-02-2018");
$data_fim = new DateTime("10-03-2018");
$dateInterval = $data_inicio->diff($data_fim);


for ($i = 1; $i < $dateInterval->days; $i++) {

    /* Cria um intervalo de 1 dia */
    $interval = date_interval_create_from_date_string("+1 days");

    /* Adiciona esse intervalo na variável $data_inicio e imprime na tela o resultado */
    echo $data_inicio->add($interval)
        ->format("d/M/Y"), PHP_EOL;
}
```

[**Demonstração no IdeOne**](https://ideone.com/ipOpIK)

Comment: Eu pensei em fazer isso com o retorno de 30, mas ai eu não saberia como pular o mês, adicionando mais 1 DIA, ele entende essa dinâmica de pular o mês?

Comment: @GustavoSouza Sim. Ele vai identificar se o dia `x` é o último do mês, caso seja, passa para o primeiro dia do mês seguinte. No link de demonstração você pode ver que ele "pulou" do dia `28/Feb/2018` para `01/Mar/2018`

Answer (score 0):

Gustavo, creio que voce precisa realizar o seguinte código

```
<?php

$d1 = '2018-02-09';
$d2 = '2018-03-09';

$timestamp1 = strtotime( $d1 );
$timestamp2 = strtotime( $d2 );

$cont = 1;
while ( $timestamp1 <= $timestamp2 )
{
echo $cont . ' - ' . date( 'd/m/Y', $timestamp1 ) . PHP_EOL;
$timestamp1 += 86400;
$cont++;
}
?>
```