# Calcular a diferença de meses

Tags: php

Tenho essa função

```
<?php
    function calcula_intervalo_custo($data_inicial, $data_final) {

        function geraTimestamp($data) {
            $partes = explode('/', $data);
            return mktime(0, 0, 0, $partes[1], $partes[0], $partes[2]);
        }


        $time_inicial = geraTimestamp($data_inicial);
        $time_final   = geraTimestamp($data_final);


        $diferenca = $time_final - $time_inicial; 


        $res_mes = (int)floor( $diferenca / (60 * 60 * 24 * 24)); 

        return $res_mes;
    }
?>
```

Que retorna a diferença entre meses a função diz que de `01/09/2019` para `01/02/2019` a diferença é de **6 meses** (o correto seriam **5 meses**), e que de `01/12/2019` para `01/02/2019` é de **2 meses** (esse está certo).

Comment: Utilize a classe [`DateTime`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/285498/99718)

Comment: O que exatamente significa o valor 60*60*24*24?

Comment: as resposta que você deixou na pergunta não estão erradas ... as diferenças não são aquelas !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obtive o erro:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare geraTimestamp()

Isto é claro porque se usar mais de uma vez a função ele vai chamar novamente a declaração a cada vez que usar a função, o que se resolve assim:

```
function geraTimestamp($data) {
    $partes = explode('/', $data);
    return mktime(0, 0, 0, $partes[1], $partes[0], $partes[2]);
}

function calcula_intervalo_custo($data_inicial, $data_final) {
    $time_inicial = geraTimestamp($data_inicial);
    $time_final   = geraTimestamp($data_final);


    $diferenca = $time_final - $time_inicial; 


    $res_mes = (int)floor( $diferenca / (60 * 60 * 24 * 24)); 

    return $res_mes;
}
```

Então depois de corrigido ao executa isto:

```
var_dump(calcula_intervalo_custo('01/02/2019', '01/09/2019')); //Obtive 8
var_dump(calcula_intervalo_custo('01/02/2019', '01/12/2019')); //Obtive 12
```

São valores totalmente diferentes dos que você citou, mas talvez imagino o porque, é que na verdade não é `01/09/2019` e `01/12/2019`, o correto seria o ano de 2020 para ambos, logo então:

```
var_dump(calcula_intervalo_custo('01/09/2019', '01/02/2020')); //6
var_dump(calcula_intervalo_custo('01/12/2019', '01/02/2020')); //2
```

- Do dia 1 ao 30 de Setembro tem 30 dias
- Do dia 1 ao 31 de Novembro tem 31 dias
- Do dia 1 ao 31 de Dezembro tem 31 dias
- Do dia 1 ao 31 de Janeiro tem 31 dias
- Do dia 1 ao 31 de Fevereiro tem 29 dias (ano bissexto)

Somando temos 152 dias, que dividido por 30 daria `5,06`, que arredonda para `5`, então o que me parece errado é esta parte:

```
60 * 60 * 24 * 24
```

Se 60 é segundos, 60 é minutos, 24 é horas, então o outro 24 deve ser dias, mas um mês tem *uma média* de 30 dias e não de 24, creio que o correto seria:

```
60 * 60 * 24 * 30
```

Se o seu objetivo é descontar os dias finais de semanas e domingos então acho que não faz sentido, porque os dias passaram de qualquer forma e na verdade você teria que descontar primeiro do valor diferença e depois calcular, isso é um **código hipotético**:

```
$diferenca = $time_final - $time_inicial - $finais_de_semana;

$res_mes = (int) floor( $diferenca / (60 * 60 * 24 * 30));
```

Mas não tenho certeza se é o que deseja, mas se for o caso talvez para remover os dias de sábado e domigo talvez você tenha que criar um loop e checar dia a dia com uma `IF`:

```
if (date('N', $dia) < 6) {
   //É dia de semana
}
```

Eu não vou sugerir um script nem nada, porque até deve ter respostas no site que já resolvem, mas não tenho como saber se este é o seu problema, até aonde parece você só confundiu o `60 * 60 * 24 * 24` quando deveria ser `60 * 60 * 24 * 30`